# How to force cp to overwrite without confirmation

Tags: linux, command-line, overwrite, cp

I'm trying to use the `cp` command and force an overwrite.

I have tried `cp -rf /foo/* /bar`, but I am still prompted to confirm each overwrite.

Answer (score 1392, accepted):

You can do `yes | cp -rf xxx yyy`, but my gutfeeling says that if you do it as root - your `.bashrc` or `.profile` has an alias of `cp` to `cp -i`, most modern systems (primarily RH-derivatives) do that to root profiles.

You can check existing aliases by running `alias` at the command prompt, or `which cp` to check aliases only for `cp`.

If you do have an alias defined, running `unalias cp` will abolish that for the current session, otherwise you can just remove it from your shell profile.

You can temporarily bypass an alias and use the non-aliased version of a command by prefixing it with `\`, e.g. `\cp whatever`

Comment: Also, be wary -- even if the alias isn't directly written in .bashrc, if *anything* else this file calls ends up calling something else which manipulates the alias for cp, you will run into this behavior.

Comment: By "modern systems" he means RHEL/centos/fedora and perhaps something else, Debian/Ubuntu does not alias cp.

I prefer RHEL on the server and used Fedora for nearly a decade, but the community support of Ubuntu and the switch back to Gnome wooed me after Nvidia killed my Fedora install. I'm `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` about it.

Comment: @RayFoss Added a `(primarily RH-derivatives)` remark :)

Comment: after doing `unalias cp` and copying whatever you need to copy, you can set alias back to its default by doing `alias cp='cp -i'`. After which, run `alias cp` so you can verifiy that it's back to default alias.

Comment: A side note: a common mistake is not to add the "*" part in the source directory and copying the directory under the destination instead.

Answer (score 434):

This is probably caused by `cp` being already aliased to something like `cp -i`. Calling `cp` directly should work:

```
/bin/cp -rf /zzz/zzz/* /xxx/xxx
```

Another way to get around this is to use the `yes` command:

```
yes | cp -rf /zzz/zzz/* /xxx/xxx
```

Comment: yes, I did unalias cp -i , now its working.. Thank you for your valuable reply.

Comment: I love that unix provides the `yes` command.  Hilarious.  And someday I may use it.

Comment: yes it was aliased, nice catch :) You can use \cp to call the original cp, easier than remembering the path /bin/cp

Comment: Yep, that's another way to bypass the alias. Kind of a neat hack!

Comment: This way is more safe.

Comment: quick alternative: `\cp`

Comment: another way for using cp without defined alias is using it inside quote sign. example:
'cp' -rf /zzz/* /xxx

Comment: the /bin/cp solved it. because it bypasses the alias of cp="cp -i"

Answer (score 156):

As some of the other answers have stated, you probably use an alias somewhere which maps `cp` to `cp -i` or something similar. You can run a command without any aliases by preceding it with a backslash. In your case, try

```
\cp -r /zzz/zzz/* /xxx/xxx
```

The backslash will temporarily disable any aliases you have called `cp`.

Comment: @zhouji The backlash disables the alias, as stated in my answer. So instead of invoking the alias `cp`, `\cp` will invoke the command `cp`. This appears to be the equivalent of running `command cp`.

Answer (score 96):

You probably have an alias somewhere, mapping `cp` to `cp -i`; because with the default settings, `cp` won't ask to overwrite. Check your `.bashrc`, your `.profile` etc.

See [cp manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cp): Only when `-i` parameter is specified will `cp` actually prompt before overwriting.

You can check this via the `alias` command:

```
$ alias
alias cp='cp -i'
alias diff='diff -u'
....
```

To undefine the alias, use:

```
$ unalias cp
```

Comment: yes, I did unalias cp -i , now its working.. Thank you for your valuable reply.

Comment: it is just "unalias cp"

Comment: also if youre using oh-my-zsh, this the cp -i alias might be coming from common-aliases

Comment: in zsh at least, you can override the alias by using ls directly, like so:

`\cp -f file.txt overwritten.txt`.

I tend to want to maintain the alias for day-to-day usage, but in certain functions and aliases, I may want to overwrite the behavior.

Answer (score 69):

As other answers have stated, this could happend if `cp` is an alias of `cp -i`.

You can append a `\` before the `cp` command to use it without alias.

```
\cp -fR source target
```

Comment: As you said, others have already stated this. Why did this get 45 upvotes?

Comment: @phil294 I guess this is the easiest way without modifying alias or removing the cp alias which may be useful for other usages. `\` Its very useful here.

Answer (score 21):

So I run into this a lot because I keep cp aliased to `cp -iv`, and I found a neat trick. It turns out that while `-i` and `-n` both cancel previous overwrite directives, `-f` does not. However, if you use `-nf` it adds the ability to clear the `-i`. So:

```
cp -f /foo/* /bar  <-- Prompt
cp -nf /foo/* /bar <-- No Prompt
```

Pretty neat huh? /necropost

Comment: It doesn't overwrite the file, just suppresses the message

Comment: @Herrgott are you saying that `-f` doesn't force an overwrite? If so I would expect a permissions issue. The point of OP was to clear the effect of the `-i` directive making the removal not interactive.

Comment: yes, it doesn't work in my case. `*user@pc-1250* /tmp/ttt: cp -f -- a/* b/`
`cp: overwrite 'b/0'? `. If i call it with `-nf` it won't ask for overwrite and won't overwrite (only copies missing files)

Comment: Coreutils v8.31

Comment: Yeah looks like Coreutils works differently than the `cp` command on my mac. They explicitly ignore `-f` when `-n` is used according to https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#cp-invocation you might try `--remove-destination` instead of `-f`

Comment: it still prompts with `--remove-destination` and it writes its prompt into stderr

Comment: I mean with `-n` first, just using `--remove-destination` instead of `-f`. `-n` is the only way I can find of clearing the `-i` flag

Answer (score 20):

By default `cp` has aliase to `cp -i`. You can check it, type `alias` and you can see some like:

```
alias cp='cp -i'
alias l.='ls -d .* --color=auto'
alias ll='ls -l --color=auto'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias mv='mv -i'
alias rm='rm -i'
```

To solve this problem just use `/bin/cp /from /to` command instead `cp /from /to`

Answer (score 17):

The simplest way for me:

```
yes | cp source destination
```

Answer (score 10):

you can use this command as well:

`cp -ru /zzz/zzz/* /xxx/xxx`

it would update your existing file with the newer one though.

Answer (score 10):

I found this

```
'cp' -rf * /data/danalonso_testing/target/
```

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/358843/how-to-replace-all-the-contents-from-one-folder-with-another-one/358851

Comment: Thanks, working with ubuntu 21.10
```cp -rf source/source_file.ext target/target_file.ext```

Answer (score 9):

`cp` is usually aliased like this

```
alias cp='cp -i'   # i.e. ask questions of overwriting
```

if you are sure that you want to do the overwrite then use this:

```
/bin/cp <arguments here> src dest
```

Answer (score 8):

```
cp -u ...
cp --update ...
```

also works.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to call the command without the alias is to use the `command` builtin in bash.

`command cp -rf /zzz/zzz/*`

Answer (score 6):

-n is "not to overwrite" but his question is totally opposite what you replied for.

To avoid this confirmation you can simply run the cp command wiht absolute path, it will avoid the alias.

**/bin/cp sourcefile destination**

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep alias at the global level as is and just want to change for your script.

Just use:

**alias cp=cp**

and then write your follow up commands.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the simpler the better. This way does not show STDOUT:

```
yes | cp -rf source destination >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply used unalias to remove the "cp -i" alias, then do the copy, then set back the alias. :

```
unalias cp  
cp -f foo foo.copy  
alias cp="cp -i"
```

Not the most beautiful code, but easy to set and efficient. I also check the alias is already set back with a simple

```
alias |grep cp
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a small text file, you may consider this way too:

```
cat my.cnf > /etc/my.cnf
```

Not sure about the efficiency or side effects for large or binary files.

Answer (score -3):

It is not `cp -i`. If you do not want to be asked for confirmation,
it is `cp -n`; for example:

```
cp -n src dest
```

Or in case of directories/folders is:

```
cp -nr src_dir dest_dir
```

Comment: Others were stating that the user-facing cp was symlinked to `cp -i` by the system, meaning they were trying to overcome the default and **force** an overwrite. It sounds like you may have confused that for being the suggested syntax, but `-n` will **prevent** an overwrite.